# list values are not binding to kendoComboBox from webservice when using kendoComboBox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

I want to bind a list of values to a kendoCombobox from dataBase through webservices.

Here is the code :

```
<select id = "CbxArea" style="width:200px">
</select>

$(document).ready(function () {
    var cmbArea = $("#CbxArea"),
        area;        
    cmbArea.kendoComboBox();  

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "FlashReportWebService.asmx/GetAreaNames",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            for (i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                area = data.d[i].AreaName;
                cmbArea.append($("<option> </option>").val(area).html(area));
            }
        }
    });
});
```

List of values are coming successfully, but the problem is that only the 1st value is showing in combobox, remaining values are not displaying (I have 16 values in list).

If i write `cmbArea;` instead of `cmbArea.kendoComboBox();` total 16 values are displaying in comboBox. Is there any problem in `kendoComboBox` for binding values from .asmx page?

I must display values in `kendoComboBox` only.

Comment: Can't you use the kendo datasource?

Comment: i have tried using of datasource but i got an error saying that "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'dataSource': object is null or undefined" as there was no data in the combobox so it showing the error i think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I replied in the Kendo forums the Kendo Combobox will not show `<option>` elements appended to the original `<select>`. You need to initialise the combobox after the options are created:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cmbArea = $("#CbxArea"),
        area;        


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "FlashReportWebService.asmx/GetAreaNames",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            for (i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                area = data.d[i].AreaName;
                cmbArea.append($("<option> </option>").val(area).html(area));


            }

            cmbArea.kendoComboBox(); 
        }
    });
});
```

Using the Kendo DataSource is also an option and would reduce your code quite a bit.

Comment: you are initializing `kendoComboBox` on each iteration... Shouldn't be one outside `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have "transformed" your `select` in a `combobox`, you can not fill directly the combobox with `options`. If you want to add new items to the combobox, you should add these items to the dataSource :

```
var dataSource = cmbArea.data("kendoComboBox").dataSource;
for (i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
    area = data.d[i].AreaName;
    dataSource.add({ text : area, value : area });
}
```

Another way is to keep the alimentation of your `select` as you have done, and transform it to a combobox after this alimentation : you have to move `cmbArea.kendoComboBox();` at the end of the success callback (after the `for` loop).

Answer (score 0):

As an optimization of what Samuel Caillerie proposes and avoiding call `dataSource.add` so many times, I do recommend building an array with the data received and the invoke `dataSource` just once:

```
var dataSource = cmbArea.data("kendoComboBox").dataSource;
var areas = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
    areas[i] = data.d[i].AreaName;
}
dataSource.data(areas);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the kendo datasource you can use this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cmbArea = $("#CbxArea"),
        area;    
    cmbArea.kendoComboBox({
    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "FlashReportWebService.asmx/GetAreaNames",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: "POST"
            }
        },
        dataTextField: "text", //Your Text value in JSON payload
        dataValueField: "value" //Your Value value in JSON payload
    });
});
```